# Characteristic polynomials of Cartan matrices of Lie algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, polynomials, lie-algebras, galois-theory

Let $L$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with Cartan matrix $C_L$ (as in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan-Matrix )

> Question 1: Is is true that the characteristic polynomial $f$ of $C_L$ has the property that all irreducible factors of $f$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$) have abelian Galois group?

This is true for all Lie algebras of rank at most 15 and especially for all exceptional Lie algebras.
In case question 1 is true, is there an easy reason why this is true?
The number of irreducible factors in type A seems to be https://oeis.org/A069930 .

> Question 2: In case question 1 has a positive answer, can the roots of the characteristic polynomial be explicitly written down in a nice way?

For example for type $E_7$ we have that the characteristic polynomial has irreducible factors
$x_1-2$ and $x_1^6-12x_1^5+54x_1^4-112x_1^3+105x_1^2-36x_1+1 $
and one can see the exact roots of the second polynomial here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x_1%5E6-12*x_1%5E5%2B54*x_1%5E4-112*x_1%5E3%2B105*x_1%5E2-36*x_1%2B1 .

In case question 1 has a positive answer we can also associate to every lie algebra $L$ with Cartan matrix $C_L$ a finite abelian group, namely the direct product of the Galois groups of the irreducible factors.
Can this group associated to $L$ be described in a nice way?
Here some examples:

```
Type $F$ has Klein four group.

Type $G$ has cyclic group of order 2.

Type $E_6$ has Klein four group.

Type $E_7$ has cyclic group of order 7.

Type $E_8$ has the direct product of cyclic groups of order 4 and 2.

Type $A_30$ has the direct product of two cyclic groups of order 15.
```

> Question 3: Do these matrices belong to a certain class of special symmetric integer matrices whose characteristic polynomials all have irreducible factors with abelian Galois group?

In fact in all examples that I looked at for symmetric Cartan matrices of quiver algebras, the irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomials always had abelian Galois group.

Comment: A number of Japanese authors, such as T. Wada,  have considered the eigenvalues of the Cartan matrices of blocks of finite groups.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I just looked at Cartan matrices of quiver algebras with finite global dimension so far.

Comment: For type $A_n$ the eigenvalues are $2+2\cos(2\pi j/(n+1))$, $1\leq j\leq n$, so the Galois group of every irreducible factor is abelian. Perhaps there are similar formulas for other types. If true, this should be known.

Comment: As a follow-up on my previous comment, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6620.pdf.